# what VBA code to use to change chart title

Tags: excel, vba

```
With ActiveChart.Parent
.Name = Cells(1, values)
.ChartTitle = Cells(1, values)
 End With
```

The above line of code only changes my chart name but not chart title, why so?

Comment: If you record a macro while changing the title that will give you the syntax you need.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes i now , but i want it to be done through ActiveChart.Parent, recording doesnt give me the answer to that

Comment: That's why you *adjust* the code the macro recorder produces.

Comment: Or maybe you can refer me a link, where i can see all the function available in ActiveChart.Parent and how to use them

Comment: @BigBen yes i adjusted i found this one line code works `ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = Cells(1, values)`  but again its not a part of ActiveChart.Parent

Comment: The property is [`Chart.ChartTitle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.charttitle) so very unclear why you want to do `ActiveChart.Parent`. `ActiveChart` is already a `Chart`. Why do you want to use `ActiveChart.Parent`? What do you think it represents?

Comment: ActiveChart.Parent is a ChartObject object; chartobjects dont have a ChartTitle property.

Comment: `Debug.Print TypeName(ActiveChart.Parent)` might help you understand...

Comment: @BigBen i was changing position, size and name with it , so i thought i can also change title with it, I am new to vba so didn't knew that

Comment: @Zer0Kelvin  thanks

Comment: @BigBen thanks and can you please refer me, where i can read about these chart property and chart objects for future better understanding

Comment: [The Excel Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel/object-model).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can try with

```
With ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Caption = Cells(1, Values)
End With
```

About that
"Or maybe you can refer me a link, where i can see all the function available in ActiveChart.Parent a"

- Select the word ActiveChart in the code
- Right click
- click on "Add control expression" and confirm
- in the window that opens at the bottom you should have the ActiveChart object
- In the code window press F8 until you see a plus sign appear to the left of the ActiveChart control expression
- click on the plus sign to navigate within the object.

You can do this with any Excel object.